# Is there a way to get the overall dimensions of an object in AutoCAD (2018)?

Tags: autocad

I have some DXF/DWG files that I imported into illustrator, but the dimensions seem off by about 5mm. I don't know how to use anymore (last used more than 15 years ago) and I can see two tools, measure and dimension tool, but neither of these are allowing me to create an overall width and height of the object, its only snapping to nodes.

Is there a way to see this information similar to how Corel Draw displays it?
[image]

Comment: yes, its just hidden by the default layout. Just load the essential classic worspace and you will find this info in the toolbar below the menus